# How to manage/keep state of complicated related objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

For a properties website I have a lot of boxes with facets

- I can turn on/off some facets based on what has been queried
- Some facets have two values - open interval, closed interval, for example "1 bed only" and "1 or more beds"
- Some facets could be selected more than once. example: I can select "apartment" and then I can select further "loft"

Currently I have

- FacetSet object which holds all the Facet's.
- Each Facet have a Value object
- Value object holds a Buckets (1 bed only, 1 or more beds)
- Bucket is holding the interval, the query, and the label for the this option (1 bed only)

And I have .to_param method in all the objects and format them as URL. But it goes very dirty and complicated to maintain/track this code.

If I have to replace a bucket in the whole this structure it becomes nightmare. Or if I want to have AND and OR logic in the buckets the code complexity will become high.

One alternative is to not format each object as an url but dump the FacetSet as JSON.

What is the best way to manage such a structure?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need this in the url, not in the session or db table?

Comment: I have to store all in the URL because someone would want to email the link, so the whole state should be encoded there

Comment: As you say in your reply to my answer, I think you might be off the mark on your approach. Certainly that gist looks horrible. Can you include in your question the concerned model/db schema; it's difficult to see what you're doing, particularly the value and bucket objects.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd have a search resource and store your data there.

Good example here:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form

Comment: Yes, I have also a search resource which is keeping all the form data objects. check the gist here https://gist.github.com/1084551 

The problem is that I loose too much effort to support the whole hierarchy and instead of helping me the abstraction is slowing me down/loosing flexibility. That's why I think that there is better way of doing it.